# exclude directory in grunt-sftp-deploy

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to exclude a directory from being uploaded via sftp using the `grunt-sftp-deploy` `grunt` plugin.

Here are my settings:

```
'sftp-deploy': {
      lean: {
        auth: {
          host: 'green-and-energy.com',
          port: 22,
          authKey: 'privateKey'
        },
        src: './build/',
        dest: '/webseiten/citysim/iev-webapp-deploy',
        exclusions : ['/build/css-lib/*', '/build/css-lib/**', 'build/css-lib/*','build/css-lib/**'],
        server_sep: '/'
      }, // end of lean
    } // end of sftp
```

What I'm trying to exclude is the folder `./build/css-lib` all it's components from being uploaded. But it doesn't work, it will be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try common syntax:

```
/build/css-lib/**/*
```

This will exclude from deploy all files, not only dir. So 'css-lib' directory will not recreated to put inside non-excluded files.

Comment: Even if this is the answer, i think it would be nice for OP to know why this line and what does this line do?!